# Use flex to align first button on the left and the rest on the right

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` that uses `flex`. I simply want to align the first button on the left, and the rest to the right. HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <button class="first-button">Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
  <button>Button 4</button>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

But all the buttons ends up on the right.
[image]

How can I align Button 1 on the left? That is:

[image]

Codepen is here https://codepen.io/mark-kelly-the-looper/pen/jOpzgVX

Comment: FYI: The duplicate for this question could be found by typing your question title into Google verbatim.

Comment: i  actually did google it using a different search term! but ya, certainly a dupe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution is to use `margin` to push it `auto` to the `left`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.first-button {
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="first-button">Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
  <button>Button 4</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The style on the button you want left aligned should be:

```
.first-button {
  margin-right : auto;
}
```